# how to give space at the bottom of page if using scroll view

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, graphics, android-xml

here i have used scroll view and I want to make a space in the bottom of page so only terms and conditions can scroll and checkable box and button does not scroll it should be in the bottom of page can you help me with the xml. I have attached a image I want a design like this where buttons at the bottom not moves  [Design Example herea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBCtA.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Common.PolcyPage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/liner_layout_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_bold"
                android:text="@string/terms_of_services"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTandC"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:text="@string/updated_date_terms"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTandC_titles" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                android:background="@color/colorTandC_desc" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_semibold"
                    android:text="@string/terms_one_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTandC_titles"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/terms_one_desc"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTandC_desc"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_semibold"
                    android:text="@string/terms_two_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTandC_titles"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/terms_two_desc"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTandC_desc"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/terms_two_desc_terms"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTandC_desc"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you can make it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:paddingRight="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="I agree with the Terms and Conditions"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:paddingRight="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="I agree with the Privacy Policy"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:paddingRight="32dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:text="decline"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="accept"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
    android:paddingRight="32dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Terms of service"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Update date"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- ADD YOUR TEXTVIEWS HERE -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

use android:layout_above and android:layout_below to define your ScrollView position

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Buttons at the bottom of screen & even below of Scroll view

Add this lime in scrollView or Parent LinearLayout

```
<ScrollView>
   android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_panel"
```

Add this at the very bottom of your xml

```
       </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
--------------- ADD HERE - Below Scroll View -------
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="center|bottom"     OR    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Decline"/>

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Accept"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if its working fine or not

Comment: This works fine when ''''android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_panel"   is placed in the parent linear layout.. Thank You

Comment: glad to know that it worked for you, you can mark the answer as correct whichever was much suitable for you & a upvote as well :)